# How do I connect micro Molex to nano Molex socket?

Tags: cables, socket, cable-assemblies

I have a Molex cable that has a bigger size than its socket. My problem is how do I connect the cable to its socket?

I sent this picture about comparison cable and the nano socket exactly in front of cable. (See below)

[image: comparison between cable and socket]

I also sent pic of the bottom of the socket which I think is solderable.

I need best idea how to connect the cable to its socket. I'm ready to solder it if possible.

Maybe there's a cable converter to do it.

[image: nano socket]

Comment: The small header looks like it might be a PicoBlade but without more pictures and dimensions it's hard to tell.  If you don't want to pay $430 for the crimper, you can get preterminated wires for a few cents each, which you could splice onto the larger wires.  Or if you don't want to cut off the larger connector, you could find the mating socket and solder the preterminated wires onto that.  I don't think you'll be able to find an inline version of the larger socket.

Comment: If this is a one-time, just gotta repair it thing, and you don't need to disassemble again, there's nothing wrong with removing the existing socket, cut & strip the wires, and solder the cable directly to the PCB.  Put some hot-melt glue on it afterward to prevent future manipulation from bending the connections, and it will last "forever"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only a couple of options:

1. Make an adapter board or cable which has a male Micro connector and a female Nano connector.
2. Replace the cable with the incorrect Micro connector with a cable that has the correct Nano connector.

Although the Nano connector on the PCB could be removed, an appropriate Micro connector will have a larger pin pitch and not fit into the same holes on the PCB.

Also, per Vir's comment, the PCB connector might be PicoBlade. If so, you might try searching for "1.25mm to 2.54mm pitch adapter cable wire Molex PicoBlade" which seemed to return some results of cable assemblies that you might be able to use.

Comment: Okay so that's mean i need to cut the micro connector on cable and change it to nano connector on cable. And don't do anything on PCB connector.

Comment: If you cut the existing cable, you may find that the wire gauge is too large for the smaller connector. This is why I would recommend an adapter (cable or board with both types of connector). Also crimping pins onto wires for these connectors is difficult unless you have the right (expensive) tools. If at all possible try to find cable with the connectors already attached.